# Can I transpose a series of midi clips to a different key?

Tags: midi, ableton-live, ableton, automation

Running Ableton live 9 Suite.

I made these midi clips:
[image]

Is there a way to automate the transposition of these chords to another key?

Ideally I would like to do this with a few key strokes if thats possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A midi transposition effect should do exactly what you're after.  I am pretty sure its parameters can be controlled via automation.

https://www.ableton.com/en/manual/live-midi-effect-reference/#pitch

Unless you want to edit the notes in place. In that case Cmd-A (select all), then use the up/down keys to transpose the pitch up and down.  Hold down shift to go by octave.

You could also use the Transform tools: https://www.ableton.com/en/manual/clip-view/#transform-tools

> the Transpose slider transposes the selection. Type a number to transpose by semitones. Type a note name to set the lowest note. Adding a “-” before the note name sets the highest note

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [pitch midi effect](https://www.ableton.com/en/manual/live-midi-effect-reference/) to transopse your midi input by semitones